# Error with MUI-dataTables when i get data from API

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NAvJ.png)`code`I tried  to get data from API and show it with MUI-dataTables
but this error occurred (you can see it in attached image) I using it with create react app
**

```
import React,{useEffect,useContext, useState} from 'react'
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import axios from'axios'
const columns = [
    {
        name: "name",
        label: " name",
        options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
     }
    },
    {
        name: "username",
     label: " username",
     options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
     }
    },
    {
        name: "email",
     label: "email",
     options: {
      filter: true,
      sort: true,
     }
    },
   ];
   

   


const options = {
    filterType: 'checkbox',
    serverSide: true
};

function Users() {
    const [users,setUsers]=useState('');
    useEffect(()=>{
      const getUsers = async ()=>{
         await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(response=>{
            setUsers(response.data);
         })
      };
      getUsers();
    },[])
    return (
        <div>
             <MUIDataTable
                title={" Users"}
                data={users}
                columns={columns}
                options={options}
            />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Users
```

Answer (score 0):

Because props `data` in MUIDataTable is required an array. While fetching API, the `users` is a string `` (because `const [users,setUsers]=useState('');`). So this error appear.

To fix, you need to update initial value of `users` is an array like this:

```
[users,setUsers]=useState([]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it worked and data are shown , but all functions (filtration , searching , pagination) doesn't work when i make option (serverSide :true ) is there any solution using hooks

Comment: It not related to this question